# How to assign Digital Ocean floating ips/reserved ips to openstack?

Tags: openstack, terraform, digital-ocean

so for an app that is based partly on openstack, I am evaluating the deployment on Digital Ocean as a testbed. The openstack deployment using kolla-ansible also bascially worked. However, while the cluster afterwards is accessible via the web, anything deployed on it seems inaccessible. Comparing this with a deployment in a public cloud, it seems that this is because the DigitalOcean openstack does not have its two public ips as floating ips or as any IPs. Based on what I read, floating ips should be attached after deployment, but all docs only talk about ip ranges, and nothing I tried worked so far.

So, what is the best/quickest way to assing DigitalOcean IPs as floating ips to an openstack deployment? Or am I way off base here and this doesn't work for some reason?
(whether this is a good idea in general is not the question here)